# Pointcloud is flipped left-right when using depth values from pybullet

Tags: 3d, point-clouds, vision, open3d

I used pybullet to get depth data of an object. I converted the depth buffer into a numpy array and then reshaped it to 500x500 which is size of my image. To convert it to pointcloud, I use open3d -

```
for x in range(real_depth.shape[0]):
    for y in range(real_depth.shape[1]):
       zi = real_depth[x][y]
       xi = ((float(x))-250)/144
       yi = ((float(y))-250)/144
       vertices.append((xi, yi, zi))
```

When I do this, the pointcloud I get is flipped horizontally. Everything Can someone tell me why is it happening?
Correct image - [image: Correct PCD]
Flipped image - [image: Flipped PCD]
I get the correct pcd when I flip my depth array left-right.

Comment: Can you share which functions you are using on pybullet side? I think that difference between coordinate frames of pybullet and open3d may cause this. If pybullet's (0,0) is left top, then this may cause problem